# Hibernate Search with embedded entity not indexed

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

Am using Hibernate Search 5.5.2. The Vehicle entity has @OnetoOne association with VehicleType  (veh_type in Vehicle has a FK relationship with veh_type_code in VehicleType). VehicleType contains pre-defined static data and hence I will only set the vehTypeCode during Vehicle insert.

Since VehicleType data is not inserted while inserting Vehicle, Lucene is not storing the associated VehicleType indexes. How do I ensure lucene to index the associated VehicleType parameters based on the vehTypeCode along with the parent entity indexes ?

```
@Indexed 
@Analyzer(definition="ngram")

public class Vehicle {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "veh_id")
private Integer vehId ;

@Field(analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
@Column(name = "regn_no")
private String regnNo;  

@Column(name = "veh_type")  
private Integer vehTypeCode ;  

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "veh_type", referencedColumnName = "veh_type_code", updatable=false, insertable=false)
@IndexedEmbedded 
private VehicleType vehType ;
.......
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Vehicle_Type")
@Embeddable

 public class VehicleType {

 @Id @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name = "veh_type_id")
 private Integer vehTypeId; 

 @JsonView(CBViews.User.class)
 @Column(name = "veh_type_code", updatable = false, insertable=false)
 private Integer vehTypeCode;

 @Field(analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
 @Column(name = "make")
 private String make;

 @Field(analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
 @Column(name = "model")
 private String model;

 ..............
 }
```

Comment: This should be automatic. You say "Lucene is not storing the associated VehicleType indexes" .. are you sure or is your query wrong? Check the index state with Luke.

Comment: I too expected this to be automatic with Hibernate Search as it understands the relationship, but it's not the case, Lucene is not storing the VehicleType indexes.  I verified this with Luke.